# TransferState: Who guarantees that data is already stored in state?

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-transfer-state

I'm doing **SSR with TransferState** and
wondering who guarantees that when we do

```
http.get(...).subscribe(data => {
  transferState.set(DATA_KEY, data)
})
```

data will be stored in **transferState**?
Because **http.get is async operation** and content could be generate and provided to client without this data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular Zone guarantees that all async operations (the calls tracked by zone.js ) to be finished before rendering.

Let's take a look at

**server.ts**

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});   
                      ||
                      \/
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
```

We can see that all regular routes use the Universal engine to render the html.

`res.render` method (1) defines [default callback](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3d10279826f59bf68e28995ce423f7bc4d2f11cf/lib/response.js#L1001).
The [ngExpressEngine](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/abcfbfb2756ccbb0489b87676cec70821752c4b4/modules/express-engine/src/main.ts#L53) function returns [another function with that callback](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/abcfbfb2756ccbb0489b87676cec70821752c4b4/modules/express-engine/src/main.ts#L66) passed as parameter (2). As soon as that callback is triggered express sends the result to the user.

```
done = done || function (err, str) {
  if (err) return req.next(err);
  self.send(str);
};
```

Now let's see when that [callback will be triggered](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/abcfbfb2756ccbb0489b87676cec70821752c4b4/modules/express-engine/src/main.ts#L93-L105). As mentioned before we need to look at ngExpressEngine function.

```
 getFactory(moduleOrFactory, compiler)
   .then(factory => {
       return renderModuleFactory(factory, {
          extraProviders
       });
    })
    .then((html: string) => {
      callback(null, html);
    }, (err) => {
      callback(err);
});
```

It will happen only after the promise(3), returning from `renderModuleFactory` function, is resolved.

`renderModuleFactory` function can be found at  [@angular/platform-server](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13eb57a59fd4db27e88edb188947297b6637177f/packages/platform-server/src/utils.ts#L96)

```
export function renderModuleFactory<T>(
    moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<T>,
    options: {document?: string, url?: string, extraProviders?: StaticProvider[]}):
    Promise<string> {
  const platform = _getPlatform(platformServer, options);
  return _render(platform, platform.bootstrapModuleFactory(moduleFactory));
}
```

You can see above that we actually run Angular application here through `platform.bootstrapModuleFactory(moduleFactory)` (4)

Inside [_render](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13eb57a59fd4db27e88edb188947297b6637177f/packages/platform-server/src/utils.ts#L33-L66) function(5) application waits for [bootstrapping to be finished](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13eb57a59fd4db27e88edb188947297b6637177f/packages/platform-server/src/utils.ts#L35)

```
return moduleRefPromise.then((moduleRef) => {
```

and after that we can see [the key](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13eb57a59fd4db27e88edb188947297b6637177f/packages/platform-server/src/utils.ts#L43) for the answer:

```
return applicationRef.isStable.pipe((first((isStable: boolean) => isStable)))
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => {
```

You can see that angular universal looks at [ApplicationRef.isStable](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13eb57a59fd4db27e88edb188947297b6637177f/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L399-L434) observable to know when to finish rendering. In simple words isStable on ApplicationRef is triggered when [Zone has no microtasks scheduled](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/13eb57a59fd4db27e88edb188947297b6637177f/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L243-L245) (7):

```
if (!zone.hasPendingMicrotasks) {
  try {
    zone.runOutsideAngular(() => zone.onStable.emit(null));
```

[image]

Comment: wow, man. for such a detailed answer I want to add extra bounty!